# Wacom tablet - how to map the "ctrl" key?

Tags: wacom, button

I have a Wacom Cintiq 13HD tablet and I'm trying to map the buttons, but it doesn't let me map "ctrl" by itself. It can be ctrl+something, but not just ctrl. How can I map the ctrl key? Is there some configuration file where the mappings are stored and I can edit them manually?

edit: I found out where the button mappings are in dconf, but manually changing a mapping to something like Ctrl or Shift doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3):

For me the following call to `xsetwacom` worked:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 2 key "Shift_L"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 3 key "Control_L"
```

Holding Button 2 to add to a selection etc. in inkscape works for me like this. I put this in the same shell script I use to map the cursor and execute it once when I have the tablet attached.

There are also ways to automate this but I have not tried this yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as I wanted to use the my tablet with Krita.

The only solution I found is a workaround: I changed the shortcuts in Krita.

So instead of using `Shift + left drag` to change the Brush size, I mapped the shortcut `Shift+B +  left drag` in Krita to do the job, then I mapped `Shift+B` to one of the buttons of my tablet and it works fine now.

Same for `Ctrl + left` click, I mapped `B + left` click in Krita.